# Effects of radius on hypersphere.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spheres, noneuclidean-geometry

I am struggling to understand how the curvature of a hypersphere decreases as its radius increases? The Wikipedia article on hypersphere does not give a mathematical or intuitive reason as to why this happens.

If anyone could explain how changing radius effects the hypersphere. The volume of the hypersphere is given by $\frac{\pi^2r^4}{2}$ where $r$ is the radius of the hypersphere. I want to know how hypersphere changes if $Lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{\pi^2r^4}{2})$.

Thanks.

Comment: In the last line of your second paragraph, you're taking a limit as $n$ tends to $\infty$. The expression inside the limit doesn't have an $n$ at all, though. Is this really what you mean?

Comment: I am sorry, by mistake. Let me edit it.

Comment: The limit you've written diverges, and seems to be unrelated to the first half of the question which is about curvature.

Comment: Think of the definition of curvature.

Comment: @Eddy I know the limit diverges, I want to know how the curvature behaves as the radius increases. Are they inversely proportional?